# Pass a list of dates to a stored procedure variable from a table

Tags: arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a data table with a value and date column. I am selecting the value and date which is closest to a given date in the stored procedure shown below. The variable `@givendate` is only currently using one date, I would like to pass in a list of given dates from another table and ask the stored procedure to loop over each one like an array.

How can I do this in SQL Server?

Thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DateMatch
    @givendate datetime 
AS
BEGIN [enter image description here][1]
    SELECT TOP 1 s.*
    FROM [MyDataTable] s
    WHERE record = 1 
    ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(ss, s.[Date Time], @givendate))
END 


EXEC dbo.DateMatch @givendate = '2020-17-04 17:58:00.000';
```

record  |  value  |   datadate
1    |     2.1 |  03-06-2021 11:29
1    |     2.6 |  03-06-2021 11:31
1    |     3.0 |  03-06-2021 11:41
1    |     2.7 |  03-06-2021 11:56
1    |     5.8 |  03-06-2021 11:59
1    |     4.9 |  03-06-2021 12:13
1    |     4.4 |  03-06-2021 12:21
1    |     4.7 |  03-06-2021 12:29
1    |     7.0 |  03-06-2021 12:32
2    |     6.9 |  08-09-2021 06:48
2    |     6.8 |  08-09-2021 06:51

```
  --datematch  table 
       record     basedate         |        matchdateinc   |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 11:28  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 11:58  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 12:28  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 12:58  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 13:28  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 13:58  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 14:28  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 14:58  |
        1    |03-06-2021 10:58    |     03-06-2021 15:28  |
        2    |08-09-2021 06:20    |     08-09-2021 06:50  |
        2    |08-09-2021 06:20    |     08-09-2021 07:20  |



 --results table 

        record |   matchdateinc    |  value |
        1   |    03-06-2021 11:28  |   2.1  |
        1   |    03-06-2021 11:58  |   5.8  |
        1   |    03-06-2021 12:28  |   4.7  |
        2   |    08-09-2021 06:50  |   6.8  |
```

Comment: [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine)

Comment: Also, don't loop, it'll perform terribly. `JOIN` to your TVP.

Comment: Is it a date range or an arbitrary set of (potentially non-contiguous) days? Also may as well show us `DateMatch` because people often do things like `SELECT MIN(ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, col, @param)))` and I think we could help improve that logic too.

Comment: Never pass a list if the list came from a table in the first place. `JOIN` will, without any exaggeration, perform 1000 times faster. It really is that much different.

Comment: added 2 source tables,  data and date match. Datematchinc increments by 30 mins from base date. By record, closest datadate to each datematchinc is taken and value returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a list of strings as a parameter in a stored procedure in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831716/how-to-pass-a-list-of-strings-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure-in-sql)